# Touchpad tap does not work Fedora WS24 on a Toshiba laptop

Tags: fedora, drivers, touchpad

I installed Fedora Workstation 24 and am having an issue when I click (tap) in the touchpad it does not work.

I tried checking for updates via `su -c 'yum update'` but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you using a Dell machine? With Fedora on a Dell, I always need to use the buttons below the touchpad to "click" something in Fedora.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe no, I use Toshiba, and the touchpad it's work correctly in windows

Comment: The touchpad works except for clicking?

Comment: @phk yes, just the clicking

Comment: what is the output of: xinput --list-props $(xinput -list | grep "PS" | sed 's/.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/')

Comment: ahh just re-read, no need for xinput, in linux touch to click need to be enabled, it's not enabled by default, just go to system pref > Mouse & Touchpad > Touchpad (Tab) > "Tap Touchpad to click"

Comment: @mikejonesey in the Mouse & Touchpad they give me just right left (general : primary button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

see pic, there is an option to enable touchpad click

UPDATE:

> @mikejonesey in the Mouse & Touchpad they give me just right left
>   (general : primary button) – saadsaad

See 2nd screengrab (tab for touchpad):

[image]

UPDATE2:

i can find these settings by running a find;

```
$ find $HOME/.config -type f -exec grep -il "Synaptics" '{}' \;
/home/mike/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/pointers.xml
```

When I have touch to click enabled:

```
  <property name="Synaptics_Tap_Action" type="array">
    <value type="int" value="0"/>
    <value type="int" value="0"/>
    <value type="int" value="0"/>
    <value type="int" value="0"/>
    <value type="int" value="1"/>
    <value type="int" value="3"/>
    <value type="int" value="2"/>
  </property>
```

When I don't have touch to click enabled:

```
  <property name="Synaptics_Tap_Action" type="array">
    <value type="int" value="0"/>
    <value type="int" value="0"/>
    <value type="int" value="0"/>
    <value type="int" value="0"/>
    <value type="int" value="0"/>
    <value type="int" value="0"/>
    <value type="int" value="0"/>
  </property>
```

UPDATE3:

gui for gnome users:

[image]

Comment: I don't have the same :'( why ?

Comment: Looks like @saadsaad is running Fedora Workstation, which uses GNOME for its GUI. The Xfce configuration won't help....

Comment: same config dir for gnome

Comment: I take that back, the file is not plain text in gnome so path is useless ($HOME/.config/dconf/user).